# ASP.Net MVC 4 Set 'onsubmit' on form submission

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following form:

```
@Html.BeginForm("ActionMethod","Controller",FormMethod.Post)
```

On submission I want to run a Javascript function, so I added the following:

```
@Html.BeginForm("ActionMethod","Controller",FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "myJsFunction()" })
```

But, it doesn't work... What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Also when I view the source in the browser, the on submit isn't even rendered in the HTML that razor outputs...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need this instead:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionMethod","Controller",FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "return myJsFunction()" }))
{
        //form
}
```

Notice the `using` this makes the form self closing, without the using you need to close it as detailed in this **[MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd410596(v=vs.100).aspx)**.

You can confirm javascript is called with this to isolate the problem:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionMethod","Controller",FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "alert('test')" }))
{
        <input type="submit" value="test" />
}
```

This should pop up an alert.

If the first one fails and the second one works, there is a problem with your js script references. This would raise an error in your browser console.

**Update**

Instead of binding your form obtrusively, if you give your form an Id you could use the following jquery instead (**[jQuery reference](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)**):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionMethod","Controller",FormMethod.Post, new { id = "target"}))
{
        //form
}

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#target").submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            myJsFunction();
        });
    });
</script>
```

This would bind when the form when the document is [**ready**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: Thanks @hutchonoid :  your example works with the alert box, but when I move that alert statement into another js function that I have in a js document that I've included in my page.. the external function doesn't get called... Any ideas?

Comment: @DeanGrobler Yes, it will probably be your script references. If you are using chrome in dev tools check the network tab. You may have a 404, if that's the case it will be your path.

Comment: Indeed it is a reference error, stating that 'myFunctionName' is not defined... But the reason it's saying that is because the way I loaded my document into the page is by using @section AddToHead { [load JS here] } Can't get around that?

Comment: Why on earth is this a better option that just putting an onclick on the button itself?

Comment: @PaulZahra There isn't necessarily only one submit button or any submit button so on the form is exactly the right place.

Comment: @hutchonoid Would be great if you added a note regarding form validation. Right now, regardless if there's form errors, the function will execute.

Answer (score 0):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form1Demo", onsubmit = "return CheckSubmit(event);" })){

//form

}

<script>

    function CheckSubmit(e) {

        var Name = $("#Name").val();

        var Roll = $("#Roll").val();

        var Price = $("#Price").val();

        if (Name == "" || Roll == "" || Price == "") {

            $("#msg").html("Please Enter All Values!");

            swal("Validation Error!", "Please Insert All Values", "warning");

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

</script>
```